# Program not taking expected Input, can't find out why

Tags: c++, for-loop, initialization, undefined-behavior

This program should take input a,b equal to the value of t, instead it seems to only take one input and then deliver the output.
For example, the inputs of:

```
3
1 2
100 200  
40 15
```

leads only to an output of:

```
3
1 2
01  
100 200
```

the expected output should instead be:

```
1
100
10
```

The program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int t;
   cin >> t;
   for(int i; i<t; i++){
    int a, b;
    int x = a%b;
    cin >> a, b;
    cout << x;

   }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried breaking up cin >> a, b; into two different commands but that didn't work. I also messed around with where the variables are located in the code. None of that helped.

Comment: `cin >> a, b;` is a bug. The comma operator does not do what you think.

Comment: You may want to read line by line like option #2 of this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/487892) and complain / exit if the format is not 2 integers in a line.

Comment: [Enabling your compiler's warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/fxhMaMe9G) will likely inform you of these bugs.

Answer (score 3):

For starters using the initializer in the declaration

```
int x = a%b;
```

invokes undefined behavior because variables a and b were not initialized and have  indeterminate values.

Also this statement

```
cin >> a, b;
```

is equivalent to the expression statement with the comma operator

```
( cin >> a ), b;
```

Instead you need to write

```
int a, b;

cin >> a >> b;

int x = a % b;

cout << x << '\n';
```

Also the variable `i` was not initialized in the for loop

```
for(int i; i<t; i++){
```

You have to write

```
for ( int i = 0; i < t; i++ ){
```

If you do not want to mix the input with the output when use the standard container `std::vector<int>` for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    unsigned int t = 0;

    std::cin >> t;

    std::vector<int> v( t );

    for ( auto &x : v )
    {
        int a, b;

        std::cin >> a >> b;

        x = a % b;
    }

    for ( const auto &x : v )
    {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

common mistakes in using std::cout and std::cin ,is using comma instead of shift operator when seprate arguments passed to std::cin and std::cout.

so you should use  "**>>**"  of  "**,**"   when pass new arguments:

```cpp
std::cin >> a >> b;
```